# What is the best way to mount PCB with only 1mm holes in a project box

Tags: enclosure, mounting-holes

I looked at an AC/DC converter suitable for my project, but according to the description it has only 1mm mounting holes (which are also input and output).

[image: PCB]

Thus, it is not possible to use plastic spacers with screw. Project box has not any built-in mounts inside. Is it a good option to solder pin headers to the board and just glue PCB to the case?

Comment: So don't buy some Alibaba PCB but something that can actually be mounted in a sensible way.

Comment: if this is supposed to accept mains voltage and give you unregulated DC out, I would be extremely cautious about using it at all for safety reasons. Don't trust cheap alibaba stuff that connects to mains directly.

Answer (score 3):

They have not left you a lot of options. It looks like they intended the board to be inserted in slots in a PCB and soldered (though that might be dubious from a mechanical pov), similar to this [Mornsun](https://www.mornsun-power.com/html/pdf/LS05-K3B12SS.html) part:

[image]

The rigid white gunk they use for immobilizing heavy parts such as large electrolytic capacitors and large inductors/transformers could be used to make this relatively reliable (at least for a consumer product).

If you have to glue it, I would suggest a glue that does not melt (eg. **electronic grade** RTV silicone) rather than something like hot glue that might melt from heating of the device. Perhaps you could 3D print something as a holder but you'd want to verify that the plastic has a high enough temperature rating (eg. polyamide/nylon) **and** is not too flammable (eg. [UL94V-0](https://blog.flexaust.com/blog/what-is-ul94v-0)).

> Burning combustion is not sustained for more than 10 seconds after
> applying controlled flame. Total flaming combustion time for 5 samples
> does not exceed 50 seconds. None of the samples burned up to the
> mounting clamp by either flaming or glowing combustion. None of the
> samples dripped flaming particles that result in the ignition of the
> surgical cotton below them. Samples did not exhibit glowing combustion
> for more than 30 seconds after removing the second controlled flame.

Do not use non-electronic grade silicone from your home improvement store. It is cured with (conductive) acetic acid and will not behave optimally in conjunction with application of mains voltage.

Comment: the white gunk is PU with relatively low shore hardness but good stiffness.

Comment: I wouldn't want to mount something this large and heavy on a cantilever just held by solder. The mornsun one is very small and low-mass, but this one has a big old transformer on it, and a massive capacitor. Seems likely to cause problems in the long run with vibration and such. All that to say, yeah, if you use this, absolutely hold it in place with some of that white gunk.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75  Maybe. I see a different (much cheaper) polymer listed but maybe it's lost in translation. But 3kg for <<1/2 the cost of 50g of 3M urethane from Digikey.

Answer (score 0):

The design for enclosure must consider the tradeoffs and requirements then determine what is acceptable.

1. reliability (unknown?) spares?
2. repairability ?
3. heat loss and temperature rise due to enclosed insulation
4. voltage breakdown from AC line transients on L (line) to nearest conductor (e-cap -ve)
5. Mounting shear strength, resonant behavior, pull strength (note 2. above)
6. ease of pre-soldering wire
7. loose parts need structural adhesive (PU)
8. LED visibility
9. ease of assembly
10. cost  (Alibaba ;)
11. flammability
12. current limiter, PTC, fuse, transorb MOV, line filter
13. testability, access to both sides or don't care?
14. local safety requirements must be met.  This does not make your DIY project a UL/CSA-approved product but might be OK for your use.
15. 4kV lightning induced spike crosstalk to DC and line filtering to attenuate
16. avoid crosstalk of line noise to DC with adhesive

Typically one would pre-wire everything neatly, then clip/shear the leads underneath flush, uses a thin spacer made of cellulose or plastic, and put a dap of polyurethane in the corners to create a thin layer of adhesive if the enclosure is metal, then secure until bonded.

I might use electrical Silicone from a tube (non-acetic acid) to insulate between L N and cap and it may be sufficient for glue but PU is stronger.  Hardware stores carry sub-floor adhesive but now takes 1 to 3 days to cure with low volatiles is exceptionally strong and doesn't need much and turns into medium-hard plastic.  If the coil gets hot and melts hot glue, that would not be cool, but allow 20% of of total power and poor thermal spreading to increase component temps so convection air is needed over a large surface. Sealing it, demands a thermal analysis with probes, for worst case ambient. Avoid > 60'C on inductor core to prevent thermal runaway, loss of inductance.

The wire PCB slots are to avoid surface contamination that reduces the breakdown voltage rating, so in order to preserve cleanliness from ionic dust, seal those gaps with silicone after assembly.

[image] [ref](https://longgang.1688.com/offer/574352690991.html)

### N.B.

Switching regulators tend to be very sensitive about crosstalk and load capacitance and although silicone and PU are relatively low like FR4 (Dk=4 approx)  a glob of silicone on the internal vias might be more than your 100 pF fingertip. I would strongly avoid bulk adhesive contact on those electrical vias. Input/Outputs are low impedance are OK.

Also, you don't want to capacitive couple lightning transients to your DC cap or output, so adding a line filter might be prudent unless you have spares ;) So avoid smearing adhesive between these vias.

This now might limit you to using dots of PU which is a stronger but adequate in the corners (only)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use those holes for any mechanical purpose at all.

I would provide a couple of holes in th emain pcb just beyond the ends of the board, sized for something like 4-40 or 6-32. I would also provide clearance holes in the main pcb for every point where a component lead is soldered on the bottom of the daughter board, so the daughter board sits perfectly flat on the main pcb. I would make a crossbar out of something like 3/32 or 1/8 aluminum bar stock with holes matching the pcb holes. I would provide a layer of neoprene foam or cured RTV (standard RTV will work well since you'd let it cure before use) on the underside of the bar. I would then run long screws from the pcb holes through the crossbar, and secure with nuts and lockwashers using something more than finger tight. The foam/RTV layer will provide compliance and a good grip on the top of the transformer to hold it firmly in place.

Then again, I used to work in aerospace, and there is an old joke about the difference between hobbyists and military: "Hobbyists think that solder has infinite strength. Military thinks that solder has zero strength."